# Sorry, you don't have access to this page when signed in as site collection administrator

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, permissions, access, access-denied

Wondering if you can offer any help.

I have a SharePoint 2013 environment that is displayed "Sorry, you don't have access to this page" to all users when trying to access any part of a site across multiple site collections.

I am currently signed in as the farm admin account and I also get the same issue.

I cannot see anything untoward in the ULS logs, the servers have been restarted we have checked all application pools, services and IIS however the error continues to be displayed.

This farm is a single server farm with multiple web applications however this is happening on one web application across multiple site collections.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify the below :

1. Check the user policy for the web application which occurs the issue
   in the Central Administration –>”Manage Web Applications”->”User
   Policy” and make sure the account has “full control” access.
2. Check the permission policy for the web application which occurs the issue in the Central Administration –>”Manage Web Applications”->”Permission Policy”->”Full Control” and make sure it has grant the “Apply Themes and Boards” access.
3. You can recreate a site collection to test whether it works properly.

Reference URL :

[Site Collection admin getting an "Sorry, you don't have access to this page" error message](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5c152c9e-ed5c-491b-a7d0-ea4a1e480dd0/site-collection-admin-getting-an-quotsorry-you-dont-have-access-to-this-pagequot-error-message?forum=appsforsharepoint)